# Elasticsearch file descriptors error with Docker on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm running on an error when trying to up an Elasticsearch container :

elasticsearch_1  | [1]: max file descriptors [65336] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]

The docker-compose.yml :

```
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.12
  environment:
    - node.name=myworks
    - cluster.name=myworks
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms126M -Xmx126M"
    - http.cors.enabled=true
    - http.cors.allow-origin=*
    - network.host=0.0.0.0
  ulimits:
      nproc: 100000
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 100000
        hard: 100000
  volumes:
        - './data/es:/data/es'
  ports:
    - '9300:9200'
```

I have also up the ulimit to 100000 on the system itself, by modify `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf`

**Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d** on Ubuntu 18.04

I have tried almost every single 'solution' I could find online but nothing works. The same docker-compose works on Mac OS.

It drives me crazy !!

Also getting this as a bonus :

`elasticsearch_1  | [2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

Any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in "vm.max_map_count=655360" /etc/sysctl.conf
stop your docker container and again start it.Hopefully it will resolve your problem